# Web - what is the differences between periodic sync and sync?

Tags: javascript, web, service-worker, indexeddb, background-sync

I came across two different types of sync in the background for PWAs ***sync*** and ***periodic sync***. there are not many resources for them and existing resources do not explain enough with sample working codes.

so my main question is: are there any other logical differences between them other than frequency?

and my side question is: are they handling requests by themselves? I'm asking this because I want something more flexible, I mean I'm managing offline and online situations and saving data in *IDB* them I'm offline and I just need a background process to get my offline data from my custom IDB and send them to the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a few use cases that can help illustrate the difference. Also keep in mind that as of Feb. 2021, the [Background Sync](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync) is only available in Chrome and Chromium-based browsers, and [Periodic Background Sync](https://web.dev/periodic-background-sync/) is only available in Chrome after a progressive web app has been [installed](https://web.dev/promote-install/).

#### Background Sync

The use case is retrying a failed update/upload operation (usually a `POST` or a `PUT`) "in the background" at a regular interval, until it succeeds. You could imagine, for instance, trying to upload a new photo to a social media site, but your network connection is down. As a user, you'd want that upload retried at some point in the future.

The API only provides the mechanism for triggering an opportunity to re-attempt the network operation, via a `sync` event in the web app's service worker. It's up to a developer to store information about the failed request (usually in IndexedDB) and actually resend it, and indicate whether the `sync` was successful or if it failed again.

(The [`workbox-background-sync` library](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-background-sync) can help with the implementation details, if you'd rather not deal with everything yourself.)

#### Periodic Background Sync

The use case is refreshing caches "in the background" so that the next time a user opens your web app, the data is fresher than it otherwise would be. You could imagine an installed news progressive web app using periodic background sync to update its cache of top headlines each morning.

Under the hood, this works by invoking a `periodicsync` event in your service worker, and inside that event handler, you'd normally make a `GET` request to update something stored in the Cache Storage API or IndexedDB.

Comment: So as I understood, it's only triggered when there is a failed network request in offline mode and we can't define and run custom requests in 'sync' event. right? I'm asking this explicitly because I save my offline-submitted data in indexedDB and I want to get them by hand in 'sync' and submit them.

Comment: Also another question: is it works when app/chrome closed in the phone or when it's running in the background?

Comment: You can register for a `sync` event whenever you'd like. It doesn't _have_  to be done after a failed request, but that's the most common time to do it.

Comment: Chrome needs to be in order for either `sync` or `periodicsync` to fire, but a page with your web app doesn't need to be open.